# passing the Client certificate over HTTP

Tags: security, http, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

We have use case where we need to pass the client Certificate and Key over Http.
And this has to achieved in a single HTTP Request. Meaning, Client will send a HTTP GET and in HTTP response we need to send the clientCertificate and keys.

I tried making below tests,

1. I generated pem file to containing client Key and cert and set the content type of http reposne as "application/x-pem-file"
    [Result] : Mozilla and chrome are not understanding  the mime type and its asking to save.

   1. if i use the mime type "application/x-x509-user-cert" , mozilla is interpreting mime type but throwing an error.

I am not sure how we can achieve this (passing client certs and keys to browser over HTTP). Kindly help us.

Thanks
Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

First you need to determine, which key you want to send. Private keys are almost never transmitted this way - that's a big security flaw. And if you send only public key - this one is already contained in the certificate.

Now canonical format for certificate is binary DER encoding. PEM and anything equally non-standard doesn't have a single chance to be recognized by the browser. I.e. what you can send and hope that it will be handled by the browser is binary DER certificate itself.

Comment: Thank for your reply Sir. I created certificate in DER format and tried to pass the only the client certificate, i am getting **This personal certificate can't be installed because you do not own the corresponding private key which was created when the certificate was requested.** on the browser.  and the mime type used is "application/x-x509-user-cert"  if i use the mime type as  "application/x-x509-ca-cert" Browser is able to download but its treating it as CA Cert. Your inputs will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Pradeep what do you want to achieve then? If you insist on sending a private key from the server, then you would have better luck with PFX file, I guess (at least on Windows).

Comment: I completely agree with you with security flaw, and same i have also communicated. but now the scenario and requirement is for TLS handshake we need to support client certificate as well, which is optional in TLS but requirement is to support. And these client certificates we need to distribute to clients from a webServer.  So we were looking for options Sir. but now eventhough if send only certificate i am getting above error.

Comment: @Pradeep Did you try packing the certificate and a key to PFX?

Comment: no luck Sir, tried with mime type "application/x-pkcs12" Chrome/mozilla is not able to interpret it. used below command to convert **openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.pfx -in client.crt -inkey client.key**

Comment: @Pradeep It makes sense to check the source code of Firefox to get to know, if it understands any content types related to certificates, and how it handles them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31403/discussion-between-pradeep-and-eugene-mayevski-eldos-corp)